# variadic template 'ambiguous call to overloaded function' seems a false error

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I try to write a template function to initialize given systems and run the app and at the end run shutdown function on initialized systems.

This code should work in my eye and intellisense doesn't give any error but compiler:

```
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(32,2): error C2668: 'initialize_these': ambiguous call to overloaded function
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(28,13): message : could be 'void initialize_these<WindowManager,>(void)'
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(18,13): message : or       'void initialize_these<WindowManager>(void)'
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(29,1): message : while trying to match the argument list '()'
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(29): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void initialize_these<Log,WindowManager>(void)' being compiled
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(29): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void initialize_these<Heap,Log,WindowManager>(void)' being compiled
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(29): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void initialize_these<SystemInfo,Heap,Log,WindowManager>(void)' being compiled
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(45): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void initialize_these<Sdl,SystemInfo,Heap,Log,WindowManager>(void)' being compiled
```

The Code:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "AppMain.h"

#include "AppRun.h"
#include "Dummy.h"
#include "Heap.h"
#include "Log.h"
#include "Sdl.h"
#include "SystemInfo.h"
#include "WindowManager.h"

static void initialize_these()
{
    AppMain::run<AppRun>();
}

template<class Type = Dummy>
static void initialize_these()
{
    if (AppMain::initialize<Type>()) { return; }

    initialize_these();

    AppMain::shutdown<Type>();
}

template<class  First, class... Rest>
static void initialize_these()
{
    if (AppMain::initialize<First>()) { return; }

    initialize_these<Rest...>();

    AppMain::shutdown<First>();
}

void AppMain::app_main()
{
    initialize_these<
        Sdl,
        SystemInfo,
        Heap,
        Log,
        WindowManager
    >();
}
```

Hope the code be clear enough.

Oh, btw. those `AppMain::initialize<>()` calls will give true if initialization failed.
I check different part of this code. It seems to me everything is alright but the variadic templates of `static void initialize_these()` function.

Edit:
I remove

```
template<class Type = Dummy>
static void initialize_these()
{
    if (AppMain::initialize<Type>()) { return; }

    initialize_these();

    AppMain::shutdown<Type>();
}
```

Compiler error:

```
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(22,2): error C2672: 'initialize_these': no matching overloaded function found
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(19): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void initialize_these<WindowManager,>(void)' being compiled
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(19): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void initialize_these<Log,WindowManager>(void)' being compiled
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(19): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void initialize_these<Heap,Log,WindowManager>(void)' being compiled
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(19): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void initialize_these<SystemInfo,Heap,Log,WindowManager>(void)' being compiled
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(35): message : see reference to function template instantiation 'void initialize_these<Sdl,SystemInfo,Heap,Log,WindowManager>(void)' being compiled
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(22,2): error C2783: 'void initialize_these(void)': could not deduce template argument for 'First'
1>C:\VisualStudio\DirectApp\AppMain.cpp(18): message : see declaration of 'initialize_these'
```

Comment: Variadic template arguments are valid when they are empty, too! `template<class  First, class... Rest> static void initialize_these()` can be instantiated with `First` only - and in this case, the compiler can't pick between the variadic template `initialize_these` and the `template<class Type = Dummy>
static void initialize_these` above.

Comment: @lubgr you are right but when I remove ```template<class Type = Dummy> static void initialize_these``` compiler give error ```'initialize_these': no matching overloaded function found``` and ```'void initialize_these(void)': could not deduce template argument for 'First'```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Rest` can be empty, so both are valid.

---

you can make the variadic one accept 2 or more argument

```
template<class Type>
static void f(){
  // do something with Type
}

template<class First, class Second, class... Rest>
static void f(){
    // do something with First

    f<Second,Rest...>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. I don't know why it didn't come to my mind. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

with `c++17` `if constexpr` you can also write it like this

```
template<class Type, class... Rest>
static void f(){
    // do something with Type
    
    if constexpr(sizeof...(Rest))
        f<Rest...>();
}
```

Comment: Very interesting! I didn't know this.